# Jenkins upload slave build to a server from master

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, master-slave

Jenkins is running in a windows machine. 
Slave is a mac building iPhone apps. (using ssh)

This configuration building successfully.
If I archive the artifact (e.g. Output/*.*) it saves in the master (windows machine). 
But when I try to run any bat command to copy files in the post build steps, it runs in the slave machine.
How can I run command in the master (Windows), in the post build steps? Or there is other ways to do it?

I want to upload the build artifact to a server accessible only from the windows (master) machine. How can I do that?

How to tell Jenkins, to take the build artifacts from the slave and run some command (copy files) on those files in the master.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Publish Over FTP Plugin. Create an ftp in master and using Publish Over FTP Plugin, copy the build artifacts to master machine.

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: The server do not support ftp. Only way to share is through active directory, in the same windows network. I want to copy in mapped network drive from the master.